# Problem with LaTeX (missing $ inserted)

Tags: errors, input-encodings

These are the first lines of my TeX document:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[catalan]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\title{Treball}
\author{nom}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\section{Introducció}
```

And this is the error that I receive:

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.18 \section{Introducció}
```

Why is this? I don't see it. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome, replace `latin1` by `utf8`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. A suggestion: Do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than "user1234".

Answer (score 20):

The error can only be reproduced if the file is saved in UTF-8 encoding.

Indeed, in this case, `ó` is really stored as the bytes `0xC3` and `0xB3`. In the `latin1` encoding, the first is `Ã` and the second is `³`, which `inputenc` translates into `\~A` and `\maththreesuperior`. The latter is in turn converted into `{^3}`, which requires math mode and this is the cause for your error.

The solution is to use

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

Depending on what text editor or front-end you use, you can check what default encoding is used for saving your files. Nowadays UTF-8 is recommended anyhow.